# How can i create path with uuid4()

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, react-router, uuid

NewsDetails

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const NewsDetail = ({ state }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      {
        state
          .filter((a) => a.id === id)
          .map((card, index) => (
            <>
              <div className="card" key={index}>
                <h2>{card.title}</h2>
                <h2>{card.content}</h2>
                <img src={card.imageUrl} alt="" />
              </div>
            </>
          ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default NewsDetail
```

NewsItem

```
import React from 'react'
import clock from "../components/assets/img/Clock.svg"
import user from "../components/assets/img/User.svg"
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const NewsItem = (props) => {
  const { imageUrl, title, author, content, date, id } = props

  return (
    <Link className="col-lg-4 p-2" to={`/detail/${id}`}>
      <div className="newsItem">
        <img src={imageUrl} alt='newsPhoto' />
        <h2>{id}</h2>
        <div className="itemBody">
          <p className='title'>{title}</p>
          <div className="line"></div>
          <p className='content'>{content}</p>
          <div className="itemfooter">
            <span><img src={clock} alt='clock' />{date}</span>
            <span><img src={user} alt='user' />{author}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Link>
  )
}

export default NewsItem
```

Home

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import NewsItem from "./NewsItem";
import SpinnerLoad from "./SpinnerLoad";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const Home = (props) => {
  const Category = [
    "all",
    "business",
    "sports",
    "world",
    "technology",
    "entertainment",
    "science"
  ];
  const { state, setState} = props;
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  const fetchValue = (category) => {
    fetch(`https://inshorts-api.herokuapp.com/news?category=${category}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        setState(res.data)
        setLoading(true)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))
      console.log(state);
      setLoading(false);
  };

  // const fetchValue = async () => {
  //   try {
  //     const data = await axios
  //       .get(`https://inshorts-api.herokuapp.com/news?category=sports`)
  //       .then(res => {
  //         console.log(res);
  //         setState(res.data)
  //       })
  //     setLoading(true)
  //     console.log(loading);
  //   } catch (e) {
  //     console.log(e);
  //   }
  // }

  const CategoryButton = ({ category }) => (
    <button onClick={() => fetchValue(category)} style={{ textTransform: 'capitalize' }}>{category}</button>
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchValue('all')
  },[])

  return (
    <>
      <div className="header-bg">
        <h1 className="mb-3">News</h1>
        <div className="btns ">
          {Category.map((value, index) => {
            return <CategoryButton category={value} key={index} />;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="news">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            { 
            !loading 
            ? <SpinnerLoad/>
             :
            state.map((data,index) => {
              return (
                <NewsItem
                  imageUrl={data.imageUrl}
                  author={data.author}
                  title={data.title}
                  content={data.content}
                  date={data.date}
                  id={uuidv4()}
                  key={index}
                />
              );
            })
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I have created a project with api. With categories it is possible to change the incoming data, but there is one thing where I want to get more detailed information when I click on the newsItem card. That api doesn't have id value, so I used uuid. Information corresponding to the id value should come with `useParams`. But it doesn't work. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that you are generating a GUID when rendering the `state` array which won't necessarily correlate to any data you are trying to match/filter by in the `NewsDetail` component.

```
state.map((data,index) => (
  <NewsItem
    imageUrl={data.imageUrl}
    author={data.author}
    title={data.title}
    content={data.content}
    date={data.date}
    id={uuidv4()} // <-- new id each render cycle
    key={index}
  />
))
```

You want to inject the `id` property when the data is fetch so that it's a stable reference that lives as long as the data does. In other words, it should be an intrinsic property of the data.

Example:

```
const fetchValue = async (category) => {
  setLoading(true);

  try {
    const res = await fetch(`https://inshorts-api.herokuapp.com/news?category=${category}`);
    const { data } = await res.json();
    setState(data.map(el => ({
      ...el,
      id: uuidv4(), // <-- map and inject id here
    })));
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};
```

...

```
state.map((data) => (
  <NewsItem
    key={data.id} // <-- use as React key
    data={data} // <-- pass entire data object as prop
  />
))
```

NewsItem

```
const NewsItem = ({ data }) => {
  const { imageUrl, title, author, content, date, id } = data;

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

NewsDetail

```
const NewsDetail = ({ state }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      {state
        .filter((card) => card.id === id)
        .map((card) => (
          <div className="card" key={card.id}>
            <h2>{card.title}</h2>
            <h2>{card.content}</h2>
            <img src={card.imageUrl} alt="" />
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
};
```